# Download XML from external site

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm creating a web app (using phonegap) that needs to retrieve an xml document from an online site. How do I do this? From what i gather, AJAX will only work on relative url's due to some security restriction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to work with `JQuery` ajax api? You will have to make the `crossDomain` option to `true` so that you can do a crossdomain request. Also, you will have to add the site to your white list domains in the PhoneGap `plist` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can query a PHP script on your server using AJAX that returns the XML content using something like file_get_contents or PHP XML SimpleXML:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_xml_simplexml.asp

Comment: I know, problem is I'm creating a web app for mobile phones (it is stored on the mobile phone) so can't use PHP or other server-side technology. All I got to work with is HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript :/

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap doesn't subject your code to the same-origin policy which prevents you from using AJAX cross-domain:

> Q. I want to create an application for phonegap to access externally deployed web services via AJAX. How can i resolve the issue with the cross-domain security policy of XmlHttpRequest?
>
> A. The cross-domain security policy does not affect PhoneGap applications. Since the html files are called by webkit with the file:// protocol, the security policy does not apply.
>
> (in Android,you may grant android.permission.INTERNET to your app by edit the AndroidManifest.xml)

From http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494770/FAQ